# How configure Kubernetes with external servers?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, pgbouncer

I have external Postgres and I want connect hem with me Kubernetes claster throuth pgbouncer.
What i need configure Kubernetes claster with Postgres?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be many tutorials on how to achieve this, you can use [this one](https://jmrobles.medium.com/postgres-connection-pool-on-kubernetes-in-1-minute-80b8020315ef) for example.